# LESS doesn't work, all looks good

Tags: html, css, less

My LESS doesn't work and I have no idea why... I have added the `.JS` after my LESS and even that doesn't help. Can somebody please tell me what is wrong ?

**index.html**

```
<!-- Loading LESS -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/flat-ui.less" />
<script src="js/less-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

**flat-ui.less**

```
// Flat UI main stylesheet that aggregates all modules
@import "config";
@import "site";
```

**site.less**

```
.top-menu {
    background: @midnight-blue; 
}
```

and **config.less** include all styles like this:

```
@mindnight-blue:      #e74c3c;
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried to add the extension .less to your imports?

Comment: I can only guess but it might have something to do with your files/paths configuration. Open the inspector->network to see what files are loaded and if all files were loaded correctly (i.e. not red).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the resources tab, if your `flat-ui.less` is loaded correctly (the mimetype is correctly set for the less file so it's recognizes as css file).

Then have a look if you get any compilation errors, because right as it stands it should throw an `undefined` error during compilation, since you have a typo in your variable name.

```
@midnight-blue   /* site.less */
   |      
@mindnight-blue  /* config.less */
```

Other than that, everything seems okay in your workflow.